# Including directories for CLion inspections while using custom toolchain

Tags: c++, cmake, header-files, clion, devkitpro

I'm using [`CLion 2018.2`](https://www.jetbrains.com/clion/) to write `C/C++` code for a [custom compiler toolchain](https://sourceforge.net/projects/devkitpro/) which are not supported natively by `CLion`. I currently compile with `make` on the `Terminal` instead of building from within the IDE.

I have a custom include directory with header files which are not resolved/found by `CLion` since they are not part of the project. However, I want to get code inspection features for them. The headers are e.g. located at `C:\devkitPro\wups\include`.

I decided to use the `include_directories()` `CMake` command to improve `CLion`'s ability to resolved code:

```
include_directories("C:\\devkitPro\\wups\\include")
```

Then I also modified the `CMake` include path:

```
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH "C:\\devkitPro\\wups\\include")
```

And also decided to link against the `lib` directory:

```
link_directories("C:\\devkitPro\\wups\\lib")
```

After doing all that, the headers still aren't resolved in `CLion` (but it still compiles using `make` of course). How can the header resolution be done with `CLion` or is it not possible, yet?

Comment: When you included via included_directories, did you check the CMake reload worked out correctly on the updated CMake scripts? Try to reload the project, if you haven't done that.
Another option here is Mark Directory As from the project view and set Source files and Header to this directory.
Or (from v2018.2) is you simply use a header/source via #include directive from the project file, then included file is treated as project one as well (should be under project root however).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the configured toolchain in `CLion`, `CMake` expects a `Windows` or a `WSL`-style path. Inspections will work with the `include_directories` directive, e.g.

```
# Add extra include directories
if (WIN32) # When using a Windows compilation toolchain
    set(WUT "/c/devkitPro/wut/include")
    set(WUPS "/c/devkitPro/wups/include")
else () # When using WSL as toolchain
    set(WUT "/mnt/c/devkitPro/wut/include")
    set(WUPS "/mnt/c/devkitPro/wups/include")
endif ()
include_directories(${WUT})
include_directories(${WUPS})
```

A more detailed written tutorial can be found in [this](https://github.com/Maschell/WiiUPluginSystem/pull/29/commits/e6bf4590bcb855a70cfa0901bfcba691975a396f) pull request.